# Google Analytics and Google Sheets integration

Tags: google-analytics

So at the moment I track pageviews via Google Analytics and enter them into a Google sheet.

Obviously this is time consuming if I have to keep track of page views of multiple projects.

Is there any way to link a specific cell on the sheet to automatically update through google analytics?

Comment: Try this: https://moz.com/blog/intro-google-analytics-add-on-for-sheets